# Cyclomatic Complexity (complexity)

Tags: javascript

I have a program for finding shortest distance/path and I got a correct answer but I am getting an issue i.e., "Function 'shortestPath' has a complexity of 9. Maximum allowed is 6." This is the algorithm

```js
const graph = {
  start: { A: 5, D: 8 },
  A: { B: 9, C: 3 },
  D: { C: 4, E: 6 },
  C: { B: 5, E: 2 },
  B: { end: 7 },
  E: { end: 4 },
  end: {}
};

function shortestCostNode(costs, processed) {
  return Object.keys(costs).reduce((lowest, node) => {
    if (lowest === null || costs[node] < costs[lowest]) {
      if (!processed.includes(node)) {
        lowest = node;
      }
    }
    
    return lowest;
  }, null);
}

// this function returns the minimum cost and path to reach end
function shortestPath(graph) {
  // track lowest cost to reach each node
  const costs = Object.assign({ end: Infinity }, graph.start);
  
  const parents = { end: null };
  
  for (let child in graph.start) {
    parents[child] = 'start';
  }
  
  const processed = [];
  let node = shortestCostNode(costs, processed);
  
  while (node) {
    let cost = costs[node];
    let children = graph[node];
    
    for (let n in children) {
      if (children.hasOwnProperty(n)) {
        let newCost = cost + children[n];
        
        if (!costs[n] || costs[n] > newCost) {
          costs[n] = newCost;
          parents[n] = node;
        }
      }
    }
    
    processed.push(node);
    node = shortestCostNode(costs, processed);
  }

  let optimalPath = ["end"];
  let parent = parents.end;
  
  while (parent) {
    optimalPath.push(parent);
    parent = parents[parent];
  }
  
  optimalPath.reverse();

  const result = {
    distance: costs.end,
    path: optimalPath
  };
  
  return result;
}
```

How to reduce complexity of Function 'shortestPath'.

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Probably helpful: [reduce complexity of if elseif conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61119733)