# Issue converting if statements to switch case

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I need to transpile a key is some situation.
Right now i'm using this:

```
  transpileKey = key => {
    if (key === 'smsCode') key = 'code';
    if (key === 'phoneMobile') key = 'phoneNumber';
    if (key === 'passport') key = 'ssn';
    if (key === 'comment') key = 'notes';

    return key;
  };
```

And the function who calls it:

```
validate = (key) => {
    key = transpileKey(key)
    console.log(key)
}
validate('smsCode')
```

I wrote this switch to make it nicer, but it's not returning the proper value (I get the last one, 'notes' in the log).

```
  transpileKey = key => {
    switch (key) {
      case 'smsCode':
        key = 'code';
      case 'phoneMobile':
        key = 'phoneNumber';
      case 'passport':
        key = 'ssn';
      case 'comment':
        key = 'notes';
    }

    return key;
  };
```

What is wrong?

Comment: No `break;` statements.

Comment: Also, a better way would be to not override the parameter's value, and simply return instantly.

Comment: @EldarB. even better would be to just use a map for this. Since that's exactly what the `switch` does except it's non-reusable. `{ 'smsCode':  'code', 'phoneMobile': 'phoneNumber', /* ... */ }`

Comment: @VLAZ can u write an example to what u meant?

Comment: @flow24 `const obj = { 'smsCode':  'code', 'phoneMobile': 'phoneNumber', /* ... */ }; transpileKey = key => obj[key];`

Comment: @VLAZ cool. is there a way to give it a default value which be the parameter it gets (the value of 'key')

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61120044